# Why HealthKit returns incorrect time?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm trying to get steps count for each hour and for this I do:

```
func retrieveSteps(completion: @escaping (_ stepsCount: Double) -> Void) {
    let stepsCount = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)

    let date = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let newDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: newDate, end: date, options: [.strictStartDate])
    var interval = DateComponents()
    interval.hour = 1

    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepsCount!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: [.cumulativeSum], anchorDate: newDate, intervalComponents: interval)

    query.initialResultsHandler = { query, result, error in
        if let stats = result {
            stats.enumerateStatistics(from: newDate, to: date) { statistics, _ in
                if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {

                    let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                    print("Steps: \(steps) for: \(statistics.endDate)")

                    completion(steps)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
}
```

And when I execute it I get incorrect date values. For example:

```
Steps: 28.3782023430627 for: 2017-10-22 10:00:00 +0000
```

but on Health app it shows time `11:58`. Why I'm getting `10:00`? And how can I improve it?

Comment: Try to format and output hour, minute and second.

Comment: @Lumialxk but how it will help me? Between `10:00` and `11:58` — 2 hours =/

Comment: I'm wondering 10:00 is your time zone, it only scale to day.

Comment: @Lumialxk maybe I'm getting wrong values?

Comment: What time zone are you in? Most likely you’re in CEST (UTC+2), while the time given here is UTC (recognisable from the `+0000` suffix). It’s just a matter of converting to local time...

Comment: @jcaron why then 1:58hrs, not full 2hrs? =/

Comment: End time vs start time maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The statistics object you get back from `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` represents a range of time the size of the interval components you provided, rather than the date of specific samples that fall inside that time range. If you want to find the date of the most recent step count sample in HealthKit, you should use an `HKSampleQuery`.